# why can't I link to a css file?

Tags: html, css

When I try to link to css file it's not updating to me in the browser, this is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

the style file name is "style.css" but it's still not working. but when I try to do the css code in `<style></style>` tags it's working

Comment: double check your css path

Comment: is your css file in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: Where is placed your css file ?

Comment: path issue obviously

Comment: Style.css should be in the same folder where your index.html is placed.. else you need to change your current path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `style.css` file in same `folder` or check your file name.

Goto your `page` `Ctrl+u` find your `style.css` and double click that link. If css code showed your `path` is right or else move the file in same folder

Comment: is there an option to do an alternative? like if it didn't found this file try another link?

Comment: You just `copy` `style.php` file and `paste` in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the style.css file is in the same folder of the HTML file.

In case you want it to be in a different folder you need to specify the full path in the href property.